# Best practices adding css/less to custom widget block

Tags: magento2, css

I created a custom widget inside my module and I'm trying to figure out how to add css to widget template. I can do it with the **styles** tag inside my template (phtml) but I assume that is not the right way?

How should you add custom css / less code to your widget block?

Comment: I think better to add it on a head block

Comment: although your css will be loaded in the frontend in general not when your widget is loaded only

Answer (score 1):

Within your custom widget module create the following file:

```
view/frontend/web/css/source/_extend.less
```

Add the following code to _extend.less:

```
@import 'widget/example.less';
```

Create your .less file here:

```
view/frontend/web/css/source/widget/example.less
```